# How add text on image with custom font?

Tags: c#, image, fonts, custom-font

I want to use a third-party font (`.ttf`). Change the font on the button works, but simply to draw the text data type does not work. No error is output.

```
PrivateFontCollection pfc = new PrivateFontCollection();
pfc.AddFontFile("Axixa.otf");

Font fnt = new Font(pfc.Families[0], 8, FontStyle.Regular);
button1.Font = fnt; // This code change font correctly

Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("1.png");

RectangleF rectf = new RectangleF(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);

Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
StringFormat format = new StringFormat()
{
    Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
    LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
};
g.DrawString("123, 123", fnt, Brushes.Red, rectf, format);

g.Flush();
g.Save();
```

Comment: post your question in English

Comment: pardon, i think it russian thread of so)

Comment: Try playing with this settings. `g.SmoothingMode`, `g.InterpolationMode`, `g.PixelOffsetMode` and remove the formatting. Take things to a minimum and check if they work. Also Idk about this but doesnt' `g.DrawString()`  ask for a location?

Comment: _does not work. No error is output._ Well this is not a helpful desription of the problem? What happens? No output, wrong font..???